# Translate PHP site trough DB or Local Files?

Tags: php, translate, multilingual

I have php db driven website that uses a lot of flash for user interaction.
I need to make it multilangual like 20+ languages.
Site is quite large and has a lot of users coming to it every day.

Other developer i work with saying we should store translation in local files e.g. /lang/english.php /lang/german.php etc.

I was thinking since database is on the same dedicated server there should not be a slow down, which way you think will work is faster?

Comment: As said below, I would probably use some kind of system that has adapters that can use multiple sources.  After that, it really just becomes a matter of how you're comfortable managing the files.  There's no reason that DB content can't be cached to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Local files are a LOT faster than DB content (Although you can save the DB output in a local cache, like files or even memcache or APC), probably not that easy to translate, but it will help you with the basic speed of implementation too, You should take a look at:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html

You can use only this part of the framework and it will give you a HUGE boost, it supports DB based translation or local files (a lot of adapters)

UPDATE:
thanks Corbin, you are right, it's better to have the direct link.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html might be a more pertinent link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's an option, but you could also use [`gettext()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php).

That way your translations are stored in local files (faster than a database) and you have the advantage that there are programs like [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) (takes some getting used to...) that you or a translator can use to automatically generate the translation files so it's a bit easier to maintain then php files.